# AWS API Gateway get request query params with '+' sign not working

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have implemented GET request in API Gateway and its working fine but today I get a name in which '+' sign is there so does anyone has any idea that **.../score?team=name+with+sign** is not working where as **..../score?team-with-dashes** works perfectly fine.
Content type of request is application/json.

Here is Body Mapping Template (application/json)

```
{
  "body" : $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($header in $input.params().header.keySet())
      "$header": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($header))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
  "method": "$context.httpMethod",
  "params": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
      "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
      "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }  
}
```

Is this something related to URL Query String Parameters or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `+` character in a query parameter is a special character. It is the replacement character for a space  character.

So if the client intends to send `.../score?team=name with spaces`, then the client may encode the URL as `.../score?team=name+with+spaces`. It may also encode it as `.../score?team=name%20with%20spaces`.

This means that on the server-side, the parameter should be unencoded with the `+` converted back to spaces.

If you truely want a `+` character in your query parameter value, then you must encode it as `%2B`, such as `.../score?team=name%2Bwith%2Bsign`.

Comment: If I use %2B then it gives me Server not found page.

Comment: Complete URL has some client's info as it is generated by our servers so I can't share here. let me create a temp user then I can share.

Comment: Don't know why this is happening but when I encode the url the api url changes itself from https://1xahqjj3ub to https://1x1xahqjj3ub adding '1x' at the start of the url and that is why I am getting server not found page.

Comment: Don't encode the URL as a whole. Instead, encode each param value before adding the value to the URL.